# Can we say that the radiator of our home is a black body?

Tags: thermal-radiation

I would like to understand the concept of Black Body through this question : can we say that the radiator of our home is a black body ?

Comment: Everything that absorbs 100% of radiation in a certain frequency will behave like a black body in that frequency (with respect to the radiation emitted due to thermal equilibrium).

What is your background? I think that black body radiation is taught in a confusing way when first encountered because most people don't really understand classical/quantum radiation emission and absorption.

Comment: I am in second year of physics bachelor

Comment: Great, is it ok with you that I will copy to an answer here something I wrote a long time ago explaining to the general public about the birth of quantum mechanics and what is black body radiation?

Comment: yes that Is perfect !

Comment: I'm fairly new to stackexchange, so I do not know if this might be appreciated or not, if writing a small physics joke is frowned upon or not, so here it goes: No, it's a white body radiator!

Comment: @Dicordi any more questions about the topic? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as said in the comments, I'm adding something long I wrote some time ago to explain better what is black body radiation. I tried to translate it from Hebrew so I hope the English makes sense. If you have any more questions regarding how this is applicable to your radiator, you are more than welcome to comment.

**How did the equilibrium problem with radiation give rise to quantum theory?**

---

What is a thermodynamic equilibrium?

Let's say we finished cooking ourselves a gourmet meal (ability we acquired during the quarantine days) and left the hot pan on the counter after we finished. What will happen to it? After a while - it will cool down and reach room temperature. Why does this happen? Because the atoms that make up the pan are fast and constantly collide with the atoms of the air near the pan, which is slower, causing the air around to heat up and the pan atoms to cool. After long enough, the "extra" energy that was only in the pan atoms transferred almost entirely to the energy in the air atoms - the room warmed up a bit, and the pan cooled a bit - until they reached the same temperature.

Similarly, for an ice block placed on the table - in the collisions between the particles in the ice and the atoms of the air, more energy will pass from the air to the ice - meaning the ice will heat and the air will cool until it is at the same temperature.

In thermodynamics, everything that can happen, will happen (for example, energy transfer from the ice/pan to the air and viceversa). In thermal equilibrium, you just demand that nothing changes - which tells you that the net flux of certain quantities will be zero, meaning temperatures, pressures, etc.. will be equal (if possible).

---

Thermal equilibrium with radiation

Now imagine a closed, black room with no particles in it at all. If the room is not at absolute 0 degrees kelvin, at any given moment there are particles in the walls that move, accelerate and collide (with each other). The thing is, when particles collide and accelerate, they emit radiation and lose some of their energy. (This comes from classical EM theory). Meaning EM theory tells us that there is a mechanism of losing energy from a material to the EM field.

Similarly, if the room was at zero temperature and there was radiation in the room, it would be absorbed and it heats the atoms - so here too one can see that energy will stop flowing from the room to the radiation or the radiation to the room when the two systems are in equilibrium.

This is exactly the point - there is nothing "mystical" about black hot bodies radiating, this is known from the classical and quantum mechanical descriptions of how matter and light interact. The point in black body radiation is that demanding thermal equilibrium (no net energy flux between the material and the radiation field) can predict the **spectrum in thermal equilibrium**. That is black body radiation! The radiation must also be in equilibrium with the material so that there is no energy leakage from one to the other! (That is, on average, the amount of energy that the substance emits will be the same as the amount of energy the substance consumes).

In other words, no room at a temperature different from zero can be dark - the room is always lit by the walls! In equilibrium, this light is emitted from the walls and absorbed in such a way that the total light in the room is always unchanged (this is the equilibrium definition)

Note that if the room is transparent, and does not interact with radiation (it does not absorb), there is also no reason to emit. In general, the more matter a radiation absorbs at a certain frequency, the more it will emit. This can be generalized and explained in further details by [Kirchhoff's law relating emissivity to absorption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_law_of_thermal_radiation), and this is the basis to the answer I gave you in the comment - your radiator is a black body only in the frequencies it absorbs well. This is also why hot gasses, which absorb and emit in specific frequencies, don't give black body curves. Therefore, the maximum radiation that can emit from an equilibrium material is indeed from black bodies, and for this situation one can calculate from equilibrium principles how much energy each radiation frequency should be.

When analyzing the result, a problem emerged - the power per unit frequency was proportional to the square in frequency, which means that as the frequency increases there is more and more energy, and it goes on and on! It can't be that equilibrium has infinite energy in radiation, so obviously something was incomplete in the laws of physics of the time ... This mystery became known as the "ultraviolet catastrophe" (because ultraviolet is in the high frequency range).

---

Planck's solution

One bright day in the early 20th century, Max Planck thought of a rather strange idea, but tried to analyze what would happen if he took a strange assumption: that the absorption and emission of radiation cannot be done with any energy, but only in whole multiples of some size that increase with frequency. In other words, Planck "manually" put a condition on the the emission of radiation to "block the problem" at high frequencies: a wall particle cannot emit any radiation at too high a frequency if it does not have enough energy for it (as opposed to classical theory, which did not have this limit). Strangely, this assumption predicted exactly the amount of radiation that is from a black body: the amount of radiation emitted was finite, and each temperature has a frequency at which it has maximum energy! These understandings helped later understand how to measure the temperature of things only by the radiation they emit (like 'seeing' a star's temperature or just measuring someone's temperature without touch).

But the solution hinted at something strange for physicists: did the interaction between light and matter really come in discrete energy packets (discrete dose = quanta)? Is really the smallest amount of energy that can be emitted or increases with frequency? This interpretation seemed like a curiosity until a patent office clerk used it to solve another mystery a few years later (The photoelectric effect). This official was named Albert Einstein, and he won the Nobel Prize after solving the mystery 16 years after he proposed his solution. And all because something didn't work out in some radiation and got swallowed up by hot things. And then quantum theory was born.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. A blackbody is an object that absorbs *all* radiation incident upon it and is in thermal equilibrium.

Neither of these are true for a household radiator. Most often they are white and so clearly don't absorb visible radiation very well. There will also be temperature gradients between the water in the interior and the surface, and/or inhomogeneities that lead to the received radiation arising from material at slightly different temperatures.

So the question is really whether a blackbody works as an approximation? Clearly it doesn't at visible wavelengths, but the bulk of the radiation is emitted in the infrared, where the absorptivity will be much higher and the approximation might be justified. Typical ways of approaching this approximation are to multiply the intrinsic spectrum by a wavelength-dependent fudge factor that is the fraction of radiation absorbed at that wavelength, or to characterise the total radiative losses in terms of an "effective temperature", which is the temperature that a true blackbody with similar radiative losses would have.